# gatsby with multiple versions of graphql - yarn resolutions

Tags: reactjs, npm, graphql, gatsby

I'm starting with Gatsby. Trying to use `gatsby-source-pg` plugin. But facing issues with multiple graphql versions. I asked author of this plugin about this issue on github and he was very helpful in answering my question.

But may be I'm missing something here..

issue - https://github.com/graphile/gatsby-source-pg/issues/3

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh.. finding out correct version is tricky..

I created fresh project with `gatsby new <project_name>` and did `npm install`.
Installed plugin with `npm install --save gatsby-source-pg`

After this I searched for folders named `graphql` in `node_modules` and then prepared following resolution list -

```
  "resolutions":{
    "eslint-plugin-graphql/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "express-graphql/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "graphql-tools/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "apollo-link/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "apollo-utilities/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "gatsby-source-graphql/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "gatsby-source-pg/graphql": "14.1.1",
    "@types/graphql": "14.1.1"
  }
```

But then somehow, when I did `yarn install`, `@types` said that it did not like `14.1.1` and and offered a range of versions. I choose the latest one from the presented list, `14.0.7` and went ahead with installation. It still generated warnings as below -

```
yarn install
yarn install v1.12.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
Couldn't find any versions for "@types/graphql" that matches "14.1.1"
? Please choose a version of "@types/graphql" from this list: 14.0.7
warning Resolution field "graphql@14.1.1" is incompatible with requested version "graphql@0.13.x"
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.7: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "gatsby > express-graphql@0.6.12" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0".
warning "gatsby > eslint-plugin-graphql@2.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0".
warning "gatsby > graphql-tools@3.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.13.0".
warning "gatsby > pnp-webpack-plugin > ts-pnp@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "gatsby-source-pg > gatsby-source-graphql > apollo-link@1.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.11.3 || ^0.12.3 || ^0.13.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 37.83s.
```

But now, I can use `GraphiQL` playground to execute my graphql queries and in the project as well.

### Update:

You can minimize resolutions and just say:

```
"resolutions": {
     "graphql": "14.x"
}
```

Special thanks to @benji from Postgraphile

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm list graphql`

Then, check the highest version you found graphql.

After that, add this to your `package.json`:

```
  "resolutions":{
    "graphql": "<highest found version>"
  }
```

Then, delete your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder.
Run `npm install`